# Will the flash light accelerate in space?

Tags: visible-light, photons, momentum, acceleration

As we know from school physics course light has pressure. So my question is will flash light accelerate in space in the direction opposite to light emission?
If not, then will flash light with attached mirror accelerate is the direction opposite to light emission?

Comment: Related to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/106369/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If I'm floating in space and I turn on a flashlight, will I accelerate?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/112866/)